# Select a directory from a dropdown and upload file

Tags: php

I am currently using the following php file upload script for a site: [File Upload with Directory Selection](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/code/455768/select-directory-from-a-dropdown-and-upload-file)

I need to be able to upload files to specific folders on the server. This script automatically populates a dropdown menu with the folders in the directory the script is running, however it doesn't include subdirectories of those folders. I'm not that great with PHP but I know at least how to do this manually with this script, but this means every time a new sub directory is created I have to go and update the script. Does anyone know how to get this script to include sub-directories automatically?

Comment: Does it display folders on the server or the client machine ?

Comment: @RohitGupta It displays folders on the server in the same directory as the  php file the script is in.

Comment: Do you really think you should be exposing your folder structure to users ?  It doesn't appear to be very safe.

Comment: @RohitGupta It will only be privately accessed and will be password protected, I understand the security risks but I'm fine with it for the purposes of this.